Maximum value of a constant in a function
I'm trying to find the maximum $B$ of the following function:
f[r_] := L (-((2 B Q)/r) + 1/2 B^3 Q r) + (
  Sqrt[r^2 + L^2 (1 + (B^2 r^2)/2 + (B^4 r^4)/16)] Sqrt[
   r^2 (-1 - (2 B Q)/r + 1/2 B^3 Q r) (-((2 B Q)/r) + 
       1/2 B^3 Q r) + (1 + Q^2/r^2 - (2 M)/r) (1 + (B^2 r^2)/2 + (
       B^4 r^4)/16)^2])/(r Sqrt[1 + (B^2 r^2)/2 + (B^4 r^4)/16])

What I did first was set some constants to simplify things a bit. So, for $M = 0.6$, $Q = 0.5$ and $L = 3$. So to get the maximum value of $B$, I first take the derivative with respect to $r$ and set it equal to zero to solve for $B$ with NSolve but it stays loading.
NSolve[D[Veff[r], r] == 0, B]

I looked for some methods to calculate with NSolve but it didn't work for me. Could someone give me a suggestion on how to get an at least approximate solution for fixed parameters $M$, $Q$ and $L$?

Do you want to find the maximum value of B for critical points of f[r] with respect to r  ?

@user64494 Exact. I'm sorry if I wasn't as clear when posting the question.

Then there is no such maximum value of B (see PS in my answer).

Somewhat changing your notations - f[r_,B_] instead of f[r_]- and making use of the sufficient condition of a local maximum of a twice-differentiable function, one obtains
M = 6/10; Q = 1/2; L = 3;
f[r_, B_] :=  L  (-((2  B  Q)/r) + 
 1/2  B^3  Q  r) + (Sqrt[
  r^2 + L^2  (1 + (B^2  r^2)/2 + (B^4  r^4)/16)]  Sqrt[
  r^2  (-1 - (2  B  Q)/r + 1/2  B^3  Q  r)  (-((2  B  Q)/r) + 
      1/2  B^3  Q  r) + (1 + 
      Q^2/r^2 - (2  M)/
       r)  (1 + (B^2  r^2)/2 + (B^4  r^4)/16)^2])/(r  Sqrt[
  1 + (B^2  r^2)/2 + (B^4  r^4)/16])
NMaximize[{B, D[f[r, B], r] == 0 && D[f[r, B], {r, 2}] < 0}, {r, B}]


{0.209128, {r -> 2.25907, B -> 0.209128}}

PS. If you want to find the maximum value of B for critical points of f[r,B], then
NMaximize[{B, D[f[r, B], r] == 0}, {r, B}]


NMaximize::ubnd: The problem is unbounded.


If you plot your solution point, Show[{Plot3D[    f[r] /. {M -> 6/10, Q -> 1/2, L -> 3}, {r, -1, 2}, {B, -5, 10},     PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {r, B, "f[r]"}],    Graphics3D[Point[ { 2.25907 , 0.209128, 0.209128}]]}] point lies outside the surface f[r,B]

@UlrichNeumann: Be careful and try {r, -1, 2.5} instead of {r, -1, 2}. Of course r==2.2590 does not belong to the interval {r, -1, 2}. I don't see in the question that interval at all. There are no constraints on r and B in the question.

You're right. There is no maximum value. I am interested in obtaining the solution you present when analyzing an interval using NMaximize but when entering it in mathematica, I obtain: NMaximize::bcons: The following constraints are not valid: {<<1>>}. Constraints should be equalities, inequalities, or domain specifications involving the variables.

@Dayzk: If it's with me, please present the whole command with that output, otherwise this is empty talk.

@user64494 Yes. I placed the first command in your answer and when I execute it, it appears:
NMaximize::bcons: The following constraints are not valid: {<<1>>}. Constraints should be equalities, inequalities, or domain specifications involving the variables.
and the entry is repeated.

@Dayzk:. Sorry, I don't understand "the first command in your answer". Please present the whole code.

@user64494 This is the error I get when I compile the code you provided in your answer. I'm sorry if I missed something https://imgur.com/MEevNNR

Here my answer Thanks @user64494 for the explanation, what QP is looking for.
F[r_, B_] := Evaluate[ f[r] /.  {M -> 6/10, Q -> 1/2, L -> 3} ]

mini[B_] :=NSolve[Derivative[1, 0][F][r, B] == 0 && -3 < r < 3, r, Reals] 
rB = Flatten[Table[ {r, B} /. mini[B], {B, Subdivide[-5, 10, 50]}], 1];
rB = Select[rB, Length[#] == 2 &]; (* all real solutions*)

sol = Map[Join[#, {Apply[F, #]}] &, rB];

maxP=MaximalBy[Select[sol, Im[#[[3]]] == 0 &], Last] 

check result
pic = Show[{Plot3D[F[r, B] , {r, -3, 3}, {B, -5, 10}, 
    PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {r, B, "F[r,B]"}, 
    MeshFunctions -> Function[{r, B}, Derivative[1, 0][F][r, B]], 
    Mesh -> {{0}}, PlotPoints -> 50, MeshStyle -> Red], 
   Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[Large], 
     Point[maxP]}]}, 
  PlotRange -> {-100, 100}]



There is not a restriction -2 < r < 2 in the question.

The result of NMaximize[{B, D[F[r, B], r] == 0}, {r, B}] ( in your notations) is "NMaximize::ubnd: The problem is unbounded".

This NMaximize[...] doesn't solve the problem QP asked for and which you explained to me. The commenad only confirms "to long for a comment"-answer.

not an answer, to long for a comment:
For the given parameters, plot
Plot3D[f[r] /. {M -> 6/10, Q -> 1/2, L -> 3}, {r, -1, 2}, {B, -5, 10},PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {r, B, "f[r]"}]


doesn't show a maximum

The explanation of the question: if B fixed there is or there is no local maximum of f in r. OP asks about the maximum possible value of B for such local maxima.
